# R# parameter hint, how do I turn it off?

Tags: resharper

Where can I turn off this feature:

[image]

R# 2018.3 eap7

Answer (score 1):

Found it...

R# => Options => Environment => Inline hints => Uncheck inline parameter hints

[image]